# Shall i have reactjs and expressjs on separate servers?

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment

I am working on a project that might scale pretty quickly and i thought that maybe i should have those two frameworks being run on two separate machines i saw some people running them on the same server, so what do you guys think, the information is quite sensitive thats another reason why i am thinking about having them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, why not ?
Reactjs is a front-side, express js - a back-side
There are not necessarily reason run them on the same server

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because Reactjs must send requests to Expressjs and Expressjs give responses. I use Reactjs on port 3000 and Expressjs on port 3001.We write port for Expressjs like a proxy for Reactjs.